# SQL Server create/update database script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, databasescripting

In MS SQL Server 2005, how can I create a script consisting off all the objects in the database (tables, stored procedures, views)? I want to use the script to create the database using SMO or to update its objects (alter, drop) if they already exist. I know about the scripting feature in SQL Server Management Studio, I am however not familiar with the configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

If versioning your database schema is what you're getting to, try [Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby). Although it does not directly support neither views nor sprocs, it supports running native SQL scripts as part of an upgrade/downgrade process.

Answer (score 0):

I use Easy Sql Tools. The deploy version is free. You can generate scripts from schemas, data, indexes, almost everything.

http://www.easysqltools.com

Answer (score 0):

There's a great tool [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) that will actually compare two databases and create a change script for you. It's a great tool for staging purposes. There's also [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) tool that will also compare lookup tables and act accordingly.

The downside is, they're not free. :(